Set $S =\{4,5,6,7\}$, $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S \times S$ such that $R$ has the minimum possible elements. What is the cardinality of $R$?
I think $R = \{(a,a)\}$ where $a$ belongs to $S$ can satisfy the conditions. As I see no reason in $\{(a,a)\}$ not being reflexive, symmetric or transitive. Thus, the answer should boil down to $1$. However, my peers think there should be at least $4$ elements in $R$. $\{(a,a)\}$ is reflexive itself and symmetric since if $(a,a)$ belongs to $R$ then $(a,a)$ must belong to $R$ as well and it does. For transitive, if $(a,a)$ belongs to $R$ and $(b,c)$ belongs to $R$, then $(a,c)$ must belong to $R$, but since $(b,c)$ does not belong to $R$ in the first place, $R$ should not violate transitivity.

The issue is that $\{(a,a) \mid a \in S\}$ as you describe is more explicitly the set
$$
R = \{ (4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7) \}
$$
which has $|R|=4$. While yes, in setbuilder form you only need "$(a,a)$" to specify $R$ (with the additional condition that $a \in S$) this is not what is relevant to the cardinality of $R$.

Sorry to cause this confusion. I meant to pick only any one of the above mentioned ordered pairs. Like if R = {(4,4)} or {(5,5)}. It was only english, I should've used Roster form explicitly. However, now that this confusion is cleared away, do you think R can have '1' element in the form (a,a) and still be equivalence?

No, because to meet reflexivity you need $(a,a) \in R$ for each and every $a \in S$, without exception -- not just one, but all elements.

Understood, this was the fundamental issue. Thankyou.

The $4$-element set $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $S$, but the OP asked about equivalence relations on $S\times S$, a $16$-element set. @PrinceDixit

@bof You are right but it is clear from their whole post that they don't master the vocabulary and what they are talking about is relations on $S$, i.e. subsets of $S\times S$.

Given any (say finite) set $A$ the equivalence relation $R$ on $A$ with the minimum amount of element is equality:
$$
xRy\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x=y.
$$
Indeed you need at least $|A|$ pairs in $R$, namely all pairs $(x,x)$, and if you take just these you get the equality relation.
